# Google maps api v3.22 - how to add a custom icon as a png file for a polyline object?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

In the Google Maps API reference, I saw there is a icon object class for using with markers :
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Icon

```
google.maps.Icon object specification
Properties :
anchor  (Type:  Point)
labelOrigin (Type:  Point)
origin  (Type:  Point)
scaledSize  (Type:  Size)
size    (Type:  Size)
url     (Type:  string)
```

But if I want to use a custom symbol for a polyline, it seems not work with a png file icon.
For a polyline, I can see that there is a "Icons" property which countains a "icon" property.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-symbol-custom
But there is a symbol object linked to this "icon" property.
Example :

```
var symbolOne = {
    path: 'M -2,0 0,-2 2,0 0,2 z',
    strokeColor: '#F00',
    fillColor: '#F00',
    fillOpacity: 1
  };
```

I have tried 1st to replace the symbolOne object by a custom png file icon like this :

`icon: symbolOne` -> replace by `icon: "icon.png"` but it doesn't work.

Then I saw too on the Animated Symbols example, that there is also a "path" property for the symbol object.

See website -> developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-symbol-animate

I have tried to replace this property value by a png icon like this :

`path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE` -> replace by `path: "icon.png` but it doesn't work.

Is there a way to associate a custom icon (png file) for a polyline object ?

Rem. I'm limited only for writing 2 links, so the 3rd link is not full.

Comment: Just add a marker to the appropriate coordinate of the Polyline.  Markers can use PNG images as custom icons.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows what you are trying to do, including an example image and polyline.

Comment: I would like to use the animation feature I could have with symbols over a polyline. With a marker, I need to write more lines code so that's not the best way I think.

Comment: You can't use a PNG as an SVG Symbol.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's right, an icon for a Polyline don't accept an image file but only a symbol that needs a SVG file path. So I need to use a marker that accept png file instead. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polyline accept a type of [Array IconSequence](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#PolylineOptions)  who have a property named "icon" who accept [google.maps.Symbol](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Symbol), no a google.maps.Icon! So png is not accepted.

Png file has no meaning inside in polyline because polyline is not a image but is drawn with mathematics, just like google.maps.Symbol. If you want you can find a svg file(a mathematics image) who represent the same thing with your png and use.

if you want to use a png you can just make a marker like this example:
https://jsfiddle.net/TomKarachristos/z8e3p70n/

```
  var image = {
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
    size: new google.maps.Size(64, 64),
    url: "http://www.bookyourparis.com/images-site/beachflag.png"
  };

  var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: 22.291, lng: 153.027},
    map: map,
    icon: image
  });


  // Create the polyline and add the symbols via the 'icons' property.
  var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [{lat: 22.291, lng: 153.027}, {lat: 18.291, lng: 153.027}],
    map: map
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer